# Removing Components from a backup

Tags: sql-server-2005, transaction-log, backup

Ok, I will start this off by: Yes, I know I should have paid more attention.  That being said, I was trying to create a full backup of my DB prior to doing truncation on a number of the tables.  When I did this, I failed to carefully inspect the destination section of the wizard.  I ended up placing my full backup inside of a *.trn Transaction Log file.  I can see it if I inspect the contents, but is there any way to remove just the Full Backup component, leaving the Transaction Log component intact?  I only ask this because the full backup is 63 GB.  I don't want to delete the existing Transaction Log in that file if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to separate the two.

You'll have to either hang on to the large file, or take a new full backup and start moving forwards from there.